# Trigger Input click event when Label Text Change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

1. I have a label with id `lblResult`
2. I have the following code:

   @(Html.TreeView(Model)
             .EmptyContent("root")
             .Children(m => m.Childs)
             .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
             .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
             .ItemText(m => m.AssetNumber)
             .ItemTemplate(
                   @
                       @*@item.AssetNumber*@
                   )
                   )
3. Then, I have the following code on the view:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("AssetTypeIndex", "ControlFiles", FormMethod.Get))`
`{`
`<div class="row">`
`<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">`
`<div class="form-inline">`
`<div class="input-group">`
`<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Search</span>`
`@Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control" })`
`<span class="input-group-btn">`
`<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search">View</button>`
`</span>`
`</div>`
`<div class="pull-right">`
`<a href=@Url.Action("AssetTypeCreate", "ControlFiles") class="btn btn-default">Create New</a>`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`</div>`
`}`

4. On script section:

   $(function () {
               var selectedData;
               $('#jstree').jstree({
                   "core": {
                       "multiple": true,
                       "check_callback": true,
                       'themes': {
                           "responsive": true,
                           'variant': 'small',
                           'stripes': false,
                           'dots': true
                       }
                   },
                   "types": {
                       "default": {
                           "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-record"
                       },
                       "root": {
                           "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                       }
                   },
                   "plugins": ["dnd", "state", "types", "sort"]
               }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                   var i, j, r = [];
                   for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i

If you see on the code above. There's a submit button which is trigger the search function on the controller. 
My question is, Is it possible to run the 'Search Function' without clicking the button? I want to run the 'Search Function' when `lblResult` received the text from jsTree, it means when lblResult text is change.

Please advice.
Thank you.

Comment: I want ask you when text in lblResult was be changed?

Comment: @BaiNguyen, it changes when I clicking a node on my jsTree. Cheers,

Comment: So i think when you click this, you had better submit search form.

Comment: @BaiNguyen, I didn't get you. I am new on MVC. Could you give an answer section please? Also, when I clicking on the node. I want to display the value also on Label. That's why I've the question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option 1: When clicking a node on your jsTree trigger that submit function by simulating a mouse-click using click method. As you know for sure the label will be changing.

@using (Html.BeginForm("AssetTypeIndex", "ControlFiles", FormMethod.Get)){
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="margin-top:-5px;">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Search</span>
                    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch" type="submit" value="Search">View</button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href=@Url.Action("AssetTypeCreate", "ControlFiles") class="btn btn-default">Create New</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
$("#submitSearch").click(); // use the code when clicking a node on jsTree

Option 2: If you are manually changing the label by entering in a textbox then use the keyup event to trigger submit function.

$(function(){
  $("#lblreasult").on('keyup', function(){
    $("#submitSearch").click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply, when you click on a node in your jsTree ex: a tag have id is node1, you can remove this code

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch" type="submit" value="Search">View</button>
 </span>
```

or add this css code

```
#submitSearch{display:hidden}
```

I edited a bit in your code

```
$('#jstree').on('changed', function (e, data) { 
    var i, j = data.selected.length, r = []; 
    for(i = 0,  i < j; i++) { 
        r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text); 
    } 
    $('#event_result').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', ')); 
    $('#lblResult').text('your text here');//
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: I use this when clicking node --> <a href="@item.AssetID" desc="@item.AssetID">@item.AssetNumber</a> ... Then on the script sect... $('#jstree')
  // listen for event
  .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
      r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
    }
    $('#event_result').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
  })
  // create the instance
  .jstree();